# Post request with Django DetailView gives error 'MyView' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create an object with django DetailView. My code is like that.

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = DetailForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            context['reply_form'] = DetailForm
            self.object = super(Detail, self).get_object()
            context['object'] = super(Detail, self).get_object()

            return self.render_to_response(request=request, template=self.get_template_names(), context=context)
        else:
            context = context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['reply_form'] = form
            self.object = super(Detail, self).get_object()
            context['object'] = super(Detail, self).get_object()

            return self.render_to_response(request=request, template=self.get_template_names(), context=context)
```

But here I am getting error that

```
'Detail' object has no attribute 'object'
```

I tried to assign object in context instance and with self as well. But nothing works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are missing here is that you have to assign the object to the class or self before calling the `get_context_data()`.

```
class Detail(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = DetailForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DetailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Write Your Logic here

            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = DetailForm
            return self.render_to_response(context=context)

        else:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = form
            return self.render_to_response( context=context)
```

and in `render_to_response()` Just pass context. No other arguments.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Perfect. After assigning `self.object` before calling the `get_context_data()` works perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: Why did you decide to do context = context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) instead of just context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)?

Comment: it was a typing mistake, It must be context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

Answer (score 5):

This is how I implemented the code from Safrazs answer to make a reply option on my question model. I know this is an old question, but I hope that someone will find this useful.

```
class QuestionDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/question.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = ReplyForm

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ReplyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save(commit=False)
            reply.creator = request.user
            reply.question = self.get_object()
            reply.save()
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = ReplyForm

            return self.render_to_response(context=context)

        else:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = form

            return self.render_to_response(context=context)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are inheriting from the wrong generic view. You need to inherit from `CreateView`, like this:

```
class CreateModel(CreateView):
  model = MyModel
  template_name = 'mymodel_detail.html'
  form_class = DetailForm
  success_url = reverse('/thanks')

  def form_valid(self, form):
     # this method is called when the form
     # is successfully validated
     # if you need to do something with
     # the database object, this is the place
     # do not use it to redirect to a success page
     # use the success_url for that
     return super(CreateModel, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `super` on the wrong class: they should be `Detail`, not `MessageDetail`. Also, you don't need the form code. Instead, use one of the generic editting views (CreateView, DeleteView, FormView, UpdateView). The DetailView is only for display purposes really. More detail on the generic views can be found at http://ccbv.co.uk/