# How to do a POST request in a DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

im following a tutorial for the project but it does it on function views and im trying to do it on class based views

i get a ( The view blog.views.PostDetailView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.) error but thats not my concern now ... because the data(new comments) arent getting saved
so how can i save them with the post request and redirect to the same page of the DetailView

my urls

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('blog/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view() , name='post-detail'),
    ]
```

my models

```
class Post(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug =  models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish_date')
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment By {self.author}/{self.post}'
```

my forms

```
class AddCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label ="", widget = forms.Textarea( 
    attrs ={ 
        'class':'form-control', 
        'placeholder':'Comment here !', 
        'rows':4, 
        'cols':50
    })) 

    class Meta: 
        model = Comment 
        fields =['content']
```

my views

```
class PostDetailView( DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name='blog/post_detail.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.object)
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['form'] = AddCommentForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.post.author
        user_comment.post = self.post
        user_comment.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

html

```
            <form method="POST">
              <div class="col-12">
                <hr>
                {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{total_comments }} comment{{total_comments|pluralize }}</legend>
                {% endwith %}
                {% for c in comments%}
                  <div class ="col-md-12 mb-1rem" >
                    <p class="mb-0"><strong>{{c.author}}:</strong> {{c.content}}</p>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ c.publish_date|date:'f A, Y'}}</small>
                  </div>
                  <br>
               {% endfor %}
              </div>
              <hr>    
              {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Comment</legend>
                  {{ form|crispy }}
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg mt-1" type="submit">Publish</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Use [**`UpdateView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Comment: doesnt that just update existing comments not create new ones

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32497740

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a long time, but I think someone might need the answer in future.

I'm using django 3.2.16.

in your post method inside DetailView:

Update your post method to:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Get the current pk from the method dictionary
    pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        # Get the current object
        obj = self.model.objects.get(id=pk)
        # Alter the field Value
        some_value = request.POST.get('some_value_from_html_input')
        obj.field = some_value
        # Save the object
        obj.save()
        
        # Redirect to you current View after update
        return redirect(current_details_view, pk=pk)
```

Comment: This is correct, but you don't need to have the if statement. Going to the post method is already assumed that it's a post.

Answer (score 0):

The DetailView has no form_valid method.
It just shows the objects of the model.

Form processing is in the GenericEdit View class.

There are many ways, but...
In this code, you can create a GenericEdit View(CreateView or UpdateView ) url, process the form there(form_valid), and then
success_url = reverse_lazy('form:detail') # in GenericEdit View class
return the template.

To sum up,

1. add path in urls.py
   like this...

`path('blog/<slug:slug>/update', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update')`,

2. add update or create url in form action.
   ex. ☞ `action="{% url 'blog:post-update' %}"`
3. make GenericEdit View class☞ `views.PostUpdateView`

ps.You can also use forms.py
"""
When you use Class Base View in django, it is recommended to refer to this site.
https://ccbv.co.uk/

and,
DetailView refer is here
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/
"""

Comment: i still dont know how to setup the updateview

Comment: UpdateView needs model and fields like this.. 
class CommentUpdateView(UpdateView):
  model = models.Comment
  fields = [ 'username','comment' ]

document is here 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

Comment: thank you, i did it on a createview .. the update was just updating existing comments